# How find this value $((\cdots((2007*2006)*2005)*\cdots)*1)$

Tags: calculus

Defining $$x*y=\dfrac{\sqrt{x^2+3xy+y^2-2x-2y+4}}{xy+4},$$ compute
$$((\cdots((2007*2006)*2005)*\cdots)*1).$$

I think this must find good $x,y$ such that $xy=const$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: $\sqrt{x^2 + 3xy + y^2 - 2x - 2y + 4} = \sqrt{(x+y)^2 + (x-2)(y-2)}$

What happens when $y = 2$?

Comment: it's very nice,Thank you